# Trailing equal signs (=) in emails

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, quoted-printable, poplib

I download messages from a Gmail account using POP3 and save them in a SQLite database for futher processing:

```
mailbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com', '995') 
mailbox.user(user) 
mailbox.pass_(password)

msgnum = mailbox.stat()[0]

for i in range(msgnum):
    msg = '\n'.join(mailbox.retr(i+1)[1])
    save_message(msg, dbmgr)

mailbox.quit()
```

However, looking in the database, all lines but the last one of the message body (payload) have trailing equal signs. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand the equal sign '=' symbol in IMAP email text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621510/how-to-understand-the-equal-sign-symbol-in-imap-email-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frederic's link lead me to the answer. The encoding is called "quoted printable" ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)) and it's possible to decode it using the `quopri` Python module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html)):

```
msg.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for python 3.x

You now have to invoke the `codecs` module.

```py
import codecs
bytes_msg = bytes(msg, 'utf-8')
decoded_msg = codecs.decode(bytes_msg, 'quopri').decode('utf-8')
```