# Strange formatting of html in SES mail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

i just set up a rule set to save incoming emails to my domain, hosted on aws to a S3 bucket. The emails arrive without problems in the bucket with an object name like the following "n19qvsrmh9kqf0ujr1aasvf96japl6isq43pfa81". I can open those objects with a standard txt editor, however when i look at the html part, it seems like the text is cut off with a "=" sign as line break. It looks like the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <style type=3D"text/css">
        .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass div,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClas=
s p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass td,img{line-height:100%}#outlook a{p=
adding:0}.ExternalClass,.ReadMsgBody{width:100%}a,blockquote,body,li,p,tabl=
e,td{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}table,td{mso-t=
able-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0}img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:=
0;height:auto;outline:0;text-decoration:none}table{border-collapse:collapse=
!important}#bodyCell,#bodyTable,body{height:100%!important;margin:0;padding=
:0;font-family:ProximaNova,sans-serif}#bodyCell{padding:20px}#bodyTable{wid=
```

I need to access a (verification) link inside the html part of the email, but it is not possible due to the "=" signs inside the link and i don't want to delete them manually. Does someone know the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is called "Quoted-Printable Content-Transfer-Encoding" as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621510/how-to-understand-the-equal-sign-symbol-in-imap-email-text) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421282/trailing-equal-signs-in-emails)