# Python Email: When trying to get the HREF link value, the value does not save with equal signs (=)

Tags: python, email, imap

Specifically I am looking for an email with the subject 'Your booking has been confirmed!' and I am trying to click the link in the body of the email. My code usually runs almost immediately after the confirmation email is sent, I am going to optimize it further to open the first email with this subject line.

Code is shown below. The hyperlink I am trying to get contains '=', but when printing or returning it, the program seems to completely remove the equal (=) signs. Apparently I need to write more to be able to post this.

I'm not sure how else to write it but let's say I have a attribute of

https://stackoverflow.com/php.?i=857398425237459">
My "value" in the code will return "https://stackoverflow.com/php.?i857398425237459." This making it impossible for me to be able to properly obtain the link information for future use.

```
import imaplib
import email
import quopri
import HTMLParser
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class parseLinks(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        global global_futures_fair_value
        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'href':
                    #print name
                    print value.type()
                    linkList.append(value)

def gmailLogin(username, password):

    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

    M.login(username, password)
    M.select('Inbox')

    rv, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
    mail_ids = data[0]
    id_list = mail_ids.split()
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])
    typ, msg_data = M.fetch(latest_email_id, '(RFC822)')

    msg = email.message_from_string(msg_data[0][1])
    msg = str(msg.get_payload()[1])
    msg = quopri.decodestring(msg)

    linkParser = parseLinks()
    linkParser.feed(msg)
    M.close()
    M.logout()
    print linkList[0]
    return str(linkList[0])

linkList = []
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
answer = gmailLogin('USERNAME','PASSWORD')
browser.get(answer)
```

Comment: The character `=` is used by the quoted-printable encoding, so `quopri.decodestring` is probably what's eating it. Do you need to decode any other quoted-printable text in the message? Is the email actually in quoted-printable in the first place?

Comment: Yeah that was the mistake! The email is not in quoted-printable so I just removed that action. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it had to do with quopri and how it encodes the message. Seen here: 
[How to understand the equal sign '=' symbol in IMAP email text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621510/how-to-understand-the-equal-sign-symbol-in-imap-email-text)