# Receiving malformed XML in email with = sign in tag name when email is triggered with swift mailer using laravel framework

Tags: xml, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm setting up and email configuration to send XML data over email with laravel's swift mailer, But somehow I am receiving a malformed XML with = signs in the tag name.

I don't intend to handle to XML, I am willing to send it into email and on the other hand I am receiving a bad XML.

This is the XML I am receiving at the other end in email.

```
<Alarm><VersionInfo>1</VersionInfo><Input1>100</Input1><EventType>PanicAlar=
m</EventType><Name>Hussain Ujj</Name><PhoneNumber>+919165905446</PhoneNumbe=
r><ExtraText>Safe Call</ExtraText><DateTime>04:53PM 02.07.2019</DateTime><L=
ocation>51.51279, -0.09184</Location><URL>http://139.59.53.253/prism_rebuil=
d/public/index.php/sos/sos/cf9b2f66-69a5-42e0-be8a-f266e80c2cba</URL></Alar=
m>
```

I have tried adding `Content-Type: text/xml` header with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit` also `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` but this thing is not working out at all.

Here is some code that demonstrate my approach:

```
$note=<<<XML
<Alarm><VersionInfo>1</VersionInfo><Input1>100</Input1><EventType>PanicAlarm</EventType><Name>Aurang Shah</Name><PhoneNumber>+917987799763</PhoneNumber><ExtraText>Safe Call</ExtraText><DateTime>04:30PM 02.07.2019</DateTime><Location>22.7003809, 75.8760245</Location><URL>http://139.59.53.253/prism_rebuild/public/index.php/sos/sos/971b89de-1868-47fb-99a4-285f2c200160</URL></Alarm>
XML;

Mail::send([], [], function( $msg )  use($note) {
  $msg->getHeaders()
  ->addTextHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding','8bit');
  $msg->to("hussainyuvasoft185@gmail.com")
  ->subject('Panic Alarm')
  ->setBody($note, 'text/xml');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand the equal sign '=' symbol in IMAP email text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621510/how-to-understand-the-equal-sign-symbol-in-imap-email-text)

Comment: Thanks for responding @Jerodev, but the link you proposed above do not offer any solutions. Although I am getting `quoted-printable` in `Content-Transfer-Encoding` with 7bit but I am seeking for a proper solution for this. In the link above it want's to handle the XML on the other hand I want to send XML in the email.