# CSV line continuation character to ignore newlines

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I'm using Python to parse a `.csv` file that contains line breaks in most values. This isn't an issue, since values are delimited by `"`.

However, I've noticed that during the construction of the `.csv` file at one point in time, long values were split into multiple lines (but kept within the same value), with an `=` character put at the end of one line to signify "the following line break is actually a concatenation". A minimal working example: the value

```
Hello, world!
How are you today?
```

could be represented as

```
"Hello, world!\n
How are you t=\n
oday?"
```

where `\n` denotes the one-byte line break character.

Does CSV have the concept of "line continuation characters"? The documentation of Python's `csv` library does not mention anything about it under [the formatting section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters), and hence I wonder if this is common practice and if Python nevertheless has support. I know how to write a parser that concatenates these lines (a simple `str.replace(v,"=\n","")` probably suffices), but I'm just curious whether this is an idiosyncrasy of my file.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be not a feature of CSV, but rather of MIME (and since my dataset consists of e-mails, this solves my question).

This usage of equals characters is part of *[quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)*, and can be handled by the [`quopri`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) Python module. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15621614/9352077) for more details.

Using this module is better than a simple `str.replace(v, "=\n", "")`, because e-mails can contain other quoted-printable tokens that need decoding and do not appear on line ends (e.g. `=09` to represent a horizontal tab). With `quopri`, you would write:

```py
import quopri
v = ...
original = quopri.decodestring(v.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")
```