# The log driver for mail is adding some extra characters in the log file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I update the Laravel version to 9. Everything is working fine after the upgrade.

I am using the Log driver for mail as I am developing on my local system but the mail content inserts in my `laravel.log` file append some extra content so it is difficult to open the URL.
The next line is converted into `=` and I don't know what is this `--443HnvBP--`.

This extra append string makes the verification link invalid (i.e 404 page).

> MAIL_MAILER=log

Here is the example (User verification email).

Text version:

```
Thanks for crea=
ting an account with InstaWP.

Verify your email account by clicking on=
 below button

Verify Email Address: http://localhost:8000/email/verify=
/3/744ff86c600429114e8bcbfcf2c38d23b227ad74?expires=3D1670592804&signature=
=3D55417e62485ca154af312bd48703c3e1849379ef7a0a0398d2378a4ae2638b04

Re=
gards,
InstaWP Team
```

HTML version (I didn't provide the entire content but you get the idea):

```html
<html>
<table>
<a href=3D"http://localhost:8000/email/verify/3/744ff86c6=
00429114e8bcbfcf2c38d23b227ad74?expires=3D1670592804&amp;signature=3D55417e=
62485ca154af312bd48703c3e1849379ef7a0a0398d2378a4ae2638b04" class=3D"button=
 button-primary" target=3D"_blank" rel=3D"noopener" style=3D"box-sizing: bo=
rder-box; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Robot=
o, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Se=
goe UI Symbol'; position: relative; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; border-=
radius: 4px; color: #fff; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; text-dec=
oration: none; background-color: #2d3748; border-bottom: 8px solid #2d3748;=
 border-left: 18px solid #2d3748; border-right: 18px solid #2d3748; border-=
top: 8px solid #2d3748;">Verify Email Address</a>
=
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
=
</html>
--443HnvBP--
```

However, these mail content are working fine with all mail clients but the real issue is with the local development.
Generally, when I was on Laravel 8, after sending a mail, I opened the `laravel.log` file and click on the link which directly redirect me to the web browser.

but now I have to manually correct the URL first which is a very cumbersome job.

Here are the details of the packages.

- Laravel Version: 9.43.0
- PHP Version: 8.1.11
- Database Driver & Version: Server version: 8.0.25 - MySQL

Comment: The equal signs are usually soft line break that shows up in all emails. Look at a raw version of any email in your mailbox, and you'll see them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621510/how-to-understand-the-equal-sign-symbol-in-imap-email-text . It probably doesn't really break your link, but you can try adding a few line breaks in your template to help the mail clients. Also your class won't actually do anything since there's no style or style sheets to specify what `button button-primary` is

Comment: No No, I generally copy the link, and yes it is breaking the link, as you can see the link now have an equal sign. and this link return obviously 404 page.